# How does this reference with '@' work in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql

I want to change all values in a column once a week. There is no condition.

I have this to do it, but I don't understand how this works.

Could someone please elucidate?

This works:

> UPDATE maxscore, (select @row := 0) r SET max_score = (@row := 50);

This also works:

> UPDATE maxscore SET max_score = (@row := 60);

Is this the best way to do this?

In my book there was an example which went like:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author WHERE

I tried like that, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: best way is to do a design that doesn't require all values to be changed once per week.

Comment: Yep. Just store the base date. Then count the number of weeks that have elapsed since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you are using works by cross-joining the `maxscore` table to a derived table that simply initialises `@row` to 0; then in the `SET` part of the query `@row` is set to 50 prior to being assigned to `max_score`. The second query also works because there's no need to initialise `@row` since it gets overwritten before being used. However, for what you're doing a simple

```
UPDATE maxscore
SET max_score = 50
```

is all you need; there is no need to use variables in the query at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've never really used mysql before, it's all a bit confusing! Your command worked great!